# Как подключить dll библиотеку в процессе выполнения кода в c++

Tags: c++, dll

Есть скомпилированная программа на QT5 (c++). В папку с программой добавляется dll библиотеки (неизвестное изначально количество) с названиями к примеру Lib_1.dll, Lib_2.dll и т.д. Программа запрашивает число подключаемых библиотек в базе данных SQL. Как можно подключать эти библиотеки в процессе выполнения программы ?

Примерная логика...:

```
int N;
N = sqlSelect(select Num from Table); //получает к примеру 18
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    include("lib_"+i+".dll");
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего, вам не должно хотеться такого, кроме очень уж странных случаев (например, вы пишете плагинную систему). Есть хорошие шансы, что вы что-то делаете не так. Расскажите, для чего вам такое.

Comment: В проекте будет использоваться "Драйвера" (dll библиотеки) для работы с устройствами, название драйвера записывается в БД, далее программа считывает какие драйвера должна подключить и подключает их. В итоге должна получиться конструкция вида for(i=0;i<n;i++) {include ("Driver"+i=".dll"); }

Comment: Хм, тогда это и правда вариант плагинного менеджера. В этом случае единственно правильный вариант в ответе: через LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать LoadLibrary!

Comment: Не забудьте поставить галочку ответу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
hModule = LoadLibrary("dll1.dll");
ptr = GetProcAddress(hModule, "SomeFunc");
ptr(1,2,3,5);
```

В общих чертах так.